# Drupal 7 Javascript Handling Not Working Correctly on Production Server

Tags: wysiwyg, javascript

Head scratcher.

I have 3 drupal 7 seven websites all hosted on the same vps server.  On my dev server which is an ubuntu 14.04 LAMP installation, all 3 sites work perfectly.  However, after uploading to the production server on all 3 sites various javascript based aspects stop working.

Things that stop working on the production server are:

1. CKEDITOR will not load - if I try to edit a page on the production server, the editor doesn't load, all I get is a white space where the editor should be.  If I switch text formats to filtered html full html (no ckeditor) everything works perfectly.
2. Colorbox overlay stops working - I am using the Colorbox module to display pdf files in lightbox overlay.  On my dev server everything is perfect and the pdf's display as design.  However on the production serever the pdf's do NOT load in a lightbox at all.  They simply load in the browser as if I never installed the Colorbox module.

Solutions that  have tried, but did NOT fix the problem:

1. Flushed Cache reloaded pages
2. Re-created & Re-uploaded db a number of times
3. Re-upload the Drupal 7 code base and the Drupal /sites/all/ folder via ftp
4. I've run the update script after uploading db's
5. I tried disabling and reinstalling the colorbox module on the production server

NOTE:  In a rush to upload I did commit a "drupal sin" and forgot to put the site in maintenance mode the very first time that I uploaded the DB.  However since then I have put the site in maintenance mode and tried all o the above steps.

If anyone has any ideas, I would highly appreciate them.

Thanx,
yupthatguy

Comment: Have you opened the browser console and looked for 404 errors? Sounds like the js files can't be found. Are the permissions on the files directory correct? If not, there should be a report on that in the admin/reports/status page.

Comment: status report says everything is fine... .. I don't know how to check for the 404 errors as you describe.

Comment: In google chrome: right click anywhere on the page, click "inspect", then select the "console" tab in the resulting window. You may have to refresh the page in order to see the errors.

Comment: you nailed it the js files are not being loaded... how do I fix it? re-uploading doesn't seem to work

Comment: where is it looking for them? I.e. what are the paths for the 404's? Get the path and go and look inside the directories on the server.

Comment: in my sites/all/libraries/colorbox  folder... I re-uploading the files via ftp now....

Comment: Go and check that the files are there when you're done.

Comment: The files are there... the upload finished...   drupal just doesn't recognize them.... I even verified the files on the production server... drupal just doesn't see them

Comment: look at the permissions on the directories on the server.

Comment: It says I have Read Write and Execute privilege on the colorbox folder.. (asssuming that it is correct, I checked the box to make recursive for all the files in the directory)

Comment: I just reloaded the page, tested, and inspected... the script didn't load... the console change and it says: GET http://ciacyleung.povertysdemise.org/sites/all/libraries/colorbox/example3/colorbox.css?nwgrzh 
judicial_corruption:89 GET http://ciacyleung.povertysdemise.org/sites/all/libraries/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js?nwgrzh

Comment: There's a misunderstanding here that might be holding you back from finding a fix - "Drupal doesn't see them" isn't the right way to think about it; Drupal will never try to see them, _your browser_ is requesting them, not Drupal. Drupal doesn't get involved in your web server serving static files, unless you alter the default .htaccess to make it so. I think it's unlikely you'll find a Drupal-related solution to this, it all points to a server mis-configuration

Comment: one last question from the noobie... production server misconfiguartion or dev server misconfiguration?  Everything works perfectly on the local dev server....

Comment: Sounds to me like the ownership/permissions on the files you're uploading via ftp doesn't allow your browser to access them. So, while the files are there, the server refuses to show them to your browser. To fix it, you'd probably need to ssh into the server as root and change ownership/permissions of the relevant file. As @clive says, this isn't really a drupal issue.

Comment: Yep, what @Ollie said. Or maybe your apache (live) config isn't serving JS files properly, or isn't serving files from that folder properly, or has an extension enabled that's getting in the way, and so on and so on...no way to tell from here really

Comment: thanks again... definitely appreciated. :-) was tired of scratching my head.. at least now I know what the problem is...

Comment: One second fellas... I compared file permissions for the colorbox folder against files in my libraries foldeer... and change the colorbox folder permissions to match...  I flushed cahce and reload page.. the javascript now doesn't show any errors at all... but I still have the problem....   now there isn't a server error and the problem is still there...

Comment: NOTE: changing the permissions to 755 for the CKEDITOR plugins folder fixed the problem... but my lightbox still doesn't work after changing permissions... hhmm..

Comment: FIXED...   for some reason the db did not save the lightbox additions to my urls...   so on my dev server lightbox would show, but live server no lightbox.   your tips got rid of the js problems (changing permissions to 755)... then I simply noticed the different urls... re-uploaded the db.. now I have a fully functional site... thanks fellas...